# Unable to register locked Google Beacon on Beacon Tools Android application

Tags: beacon, google-beacon-platform

I was trying to register a Google Beacon using the Beacon Tools Android app. However, on tapping "Register as Ephemeral ID", I get the following message:
[image]

I'm wondering if there is a way to get the password. As far as I know, this beacon was never used or registered.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what kind of Beacons are you using? Depending on the manufactor they may have a special function to become unlocked. I'm using Beacons from Beaconinside and they have a small button on the circuit board that I have to press when I want to configure them. To register such a Beacon with EID I need to press the button and afterwards I have to enter 32 '0' into the "Unlock Beacon" dialog.

You should ask the manufactor of your Beacons for more details.